# XQuery - Why does for $x in //loan differ from for $x in //loans and using $x/loan?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a xml file.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF -8"?>
<library>
<books>
    <book>
        <title>The story of My Life</title>
        <accessionNumber val = "1"/>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>The Parody</title>
        <accessionNumber val = "2"/>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>The Automata Theory</title>
        <accessionNumber val = "3"/>
    </book>
</books>
<loans>
    <loan book="1" user="35" dueDate="2006-April-10-05:00"/>
    <loan book="2" user="36" dueDate="2015-May-10-05:00"/>
    <loan book="3" user="36" dueDate="2014-November-10-05:00"/>
</loans>
<users>
    <user> <name> Fred Jones</name> <id val = "35"/> </user>
    <user> <name> Aadeem Nus</name> <id val = "36"/> </user>
</users>
```

I have to find (a) list of all the loans, sorted by user name

(b) users borrowed more than one book

My solution for (a) I have solved. Solved xquery is:

```
for $u in doc("lib.xml")//user
for $l in doc("lib.xml")//loan
where $l/@user = $u/id/@val 
order by $u/name
return $u/name
```

But it took a long because I was trying with

```
for $u in doc("lib.xml")//users
for $l in doc("lib.xml")//loans
where $l/loan/@user = $u/user/id/@val 
order by $u/user/name
return $u/user/name
```

I see no difference between them. What is the difference?

(b) Same problem like (a). I solved after a long time. Solved one:

```
for $u_n in doc("lib.xml")//user 
for $x at $xPos in doc("lib.xml")//loan
for $y at $yPos in doc("lib.xml")//loan
where $x/@user = $y/@user
and $xPos < $yPos
and $u_n/id/@val = $x/@user
return data($u_n/name)
```

And the unsolved one (which is same as solved one according to me):

```
for $u_n in doc("lib.xml")//user 
for $x at $xPos in doc("lib.xml")//loans
for $y at $yPos in doc("lib.xml")//loans
where $x/loan/@user = $y/loan/@user
and $xPos < $yPos
and $u_n/id/@val = $x/loan/@user
return data($u_n/name)
```

Can anyone please give explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: The key point is that `for $y in //loans` will assign a `<loan>` element at each step of the loop - and attempting to address `loan/loan` is obviously failing. It's the same for all the other iterations.

Comment: This looks more like a long string of homework problems, not a specific technical question. SO is a better forum for the latter.

Comment: It already solved. My question is what is the difference and why is it not working ?

Comment: So you're ONLY asking the first question? Take the others out, then.

Comment: DONE! Now please give a explanation.

Comment: I've tried to refine my answer to make it clear. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for a difference between

```
for $u in doc("lib.xml")//user
for $l in doc("lib.xml")//loan
where $l/@user = $u/id/@val 
order by $u/name
return $u/name
```

and

```
for $u in doc("lib.xml")//users
for $l in doc("lib.xml")//loans
where $l/loan/@user = $u/user/id/@val 
order by $u/user/name
return $u/user/name
```

...is that only the former iterates over individual `user` elements. The second "iterates" over `users` elements, of which there are only one, so no actual iteration occurs at all.

When you let `$l` point at `loans` and use `$l/loan/@user`, you're asking if **any loan at all** contains a match -- without looking with any specificity at **which** loan matched, because `$l` doesn't point to a single loan! Consequently, your `return` expression has no way of addressing the specific match, because its `$l` doesn't look at an individual matched `loan`, but at their joint parent, `loans`.

---

Similarly, `for $x at $xPos in doc("lib.xml")//loans` only finds one `loans` element; it doesn't look at the `loan` elements inside of it, because you aren't telling it to do so.

If you wanted `$x` to be a `loan` element, not a `loans` element, you'd need to either fix it the way you already did, or do this:

```
for $x at $xPos in doc("lib.xml")//loans/*
```